# Spring AbstractExcelView - set URL dynamically

Tags: java, spring, excel, apache-poi

The `AbstractExcelView` takes a URL which points to an Excel workbook to use (i.e. a template).

Rather than specifying this URL at container creation time, I would like to alter it dynamically.  What I'm trying to do is reuse the same view for multiple Excel formats (i.e. one is styled for screen, one for print).  Within the request, I have a variable which determines the format based on a user selection.

How can I set the URL dynamically based on this request variable?  When my request variable is "print", I want the Excel template used to be "excel/printable", but when the variable is "screen", I want the Excel template used to be "excel/fancy".  Just setting the URL within the required method `buildExcelDocument()` doesn't do it, as the workbook is already initialized here.

The closest thing I've found that might initialize this (and I had high hopes) is the class method `getTemplateSource(String url, HttpServletRequest request)...` but when I call this I get a file data error when the Excel document opens and it is empty.

Comment: The exact error I get when using "getTemplateSource(String url, HttpServletRequest request)" is "File error: data may have been lost".  It's as if the stream was already attached to the empty workbook when I switched it to the template, corrupting the stream received (speculating here).  I think I need to set this earlier than within buildExcelDocument, but I don't know where outside of config...

Comment: Looking at the source code, it's the final method renderMergedOutputModel() where the initialization takes place.  The initialization is the same as what I was trying within buildExcelDocument, so I'm stumped why my attempt isn't working...